How do I cast an Eigen VectorXd value into a double?
My problem should be simple, but I have not been able to get it to work.  I need to generate a random number from Eigen, set its range,  and assign it t0 a double.  It fails with all combinations I've tried, including what was suggested in another post.
double Trand = Eigen::VectorXd(1) *0.5 + 0.5;

I get an error indicating that "+0.5" is a double and not an Eigen vector.  So I tried this:
double Trand = Eigen::VectorXd(1).cast<double>() * 0.5 + 0.5;

Same error comes up flagging the addition operation but not the multiplication.
This was suggested as a solution in a previous post, but has failed the same was as above.
m = LO+(ArrayXXd::Random(m,n)*0.5+0.5)*(HI-LO)

Any assistance appreciated.

The proper way to extract a scalar from a 1-sized vector is value(). Note also that using a dynamically sized type like VectorXd is very wasteful here since it forces a temporary dynamic allocation. This would be more efficient:
using Vector1d = Eigen::Matrix<double, 1, 1>;
double Trand = Vector1d::Random().value() * 0.5 + 0.5;

However, Eigen's random number generation is not good for production use. It's more a debugging and testing tool. They warn:

Note that all functions generating random matrices are not re-entrant nor thread-safe. Those include DenseBase::Random(), and DenseBase::setRandom() despite a call to Eigen::initParallel(). This is because these functions are based on std::rand which is not re-entrant. For thread-safe random generator, we recommend the use of c++11 random generators or boost::random.

rand() is also not guaranteed to provide high values of randomness. Use the modern C++ generators. Looks like you want the uniform real distribution. Workable example is included there.

Thank you for the clarification, but even more for pointing me to a better random number generator.  I tried EigenRand but it is out of date and does not support the current version of Eigen.    All that remains is the opposite problem:  that of assigning a double to a Vector1d.  Any recommendations on the best way to do that?

Well, I just gave the obvious a try and it works well.  At least I learned a lot about casting in figuring this out.  But the whole thing compiles and does what is expected now.  I'm very happy to have the better random number generator as that's key to our program.
